# How to remove/delete a vanished file?

Tags: rsync

```
[macek ~]$ rysnc -av /src /dest

building file list ... file has vanished: "/src/file.ext"
```

This will not generate error:
`[macek /src]$ rm file.ext`

Also strange:
`[macek /src]$ fi` <kbd>Tab</kbd>
The path will be auto-completed to **file.ext**

What is this phenomenon and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "vanished" file is already deleted. When rsync begins execution is creates a file list. This error means that from the time it built the list of files to transfer, to the time when it was going to copy it, the file was moved or removed and it could not find it. This could be the result of a background indexing process or similar. The rsync FAQ outlines a method to [ignore the "vanished files" warning](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/FAQ.html#10).

Comment: I remember deleting the file in question almost a week ago and I've never done an rysnc before. How was rsync able to see it?

Comment: @smotch Do you have another file with a similar name? I believe it may also do this if the file is modified during the sync. It shouldn't see deleted files though. If you're positive you've deleted it theres nothing to worry about. You can use the above script to ignore the warnings.

Comment: No file with similar name; I'll just ignore it :)